# MongoDB — сохранение записи с ключом в Map в виде сложного объекта SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mongodb, maven

Всем привет! Я использую в своём `SpringBoot` приложении базу данных `MongoDB` и я пытаюсь сохранить туда объект, который содержит в себе класс `HttpHeaders`, то есть примерно так:

```
public class ResponseDefinition {
    ...
    private final HttpHeaders headers;
    ...
}
```

А сам класс `HttpHeaders` содержит в себе только одно поле:

```
public class HttpHeaders {
    ...
    private final Multimap<CaseInsensitiveKey, String> headers;
    ...
}
```

И вот класс `CaseInsensitiveKey`:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveKey {
    ...
    private final String key;
    private int hash;
    ...
}
```

При попытке засейвить класс ResponseDefinition у меня возникает исключение `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot use a complex object as a key value.` из-за того, что в классе HttpHeaders используется в качестве ключа сложный объект (кстати класс `Multimap` из пакета `com.google.common.collect`). Никакие из представленных классов я менять не могу так как они все библиотечные. Как мне правильно настроить? Если нужна ещё какая то информацию — пишите.

Comment: Возможно стоить использовать другой объект, а не `HttpHeaders`? Например можно использовать лист, в котором будут объекты, содержащие ключ-значение.

Comment: Привет, проблему уже давно решил, но если отвечать тебе, то как я и написал `Никакие из представленных классов я менять не могу так как они все библиотечные.`. Решение было использовать кастомный `ObjectMapper`, который встроен в библиотеку — он умеет это парсить. Просто не хотелось самому его настраивать)